# "Generate" labels from data swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I have

```
["06:58"]
["07:13", "07:38", "07:53"]
["08:13", "08:38", "08:53"]
["09:13", "09:33", "09:53"]
```

and I want to show it in `tableView` as in picture:

[image]

every element - it's `UILabel`, I created `class TimeViewCell: UITableViewCell` where have property `var labels = [UILabel]()` but I don't know how to push data from my array in my function:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTime", for: indexPath) as! TimeViewCell
        let showHour = self.infoWripper.sorted(by: { $0.hour < $1.hour })

        cell.labelTime.text = showHour[indexPath.row].showHour()

        for data in showHour {

            print(data.showFullTime()) //here you see my example of data in console
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create collectionView inside uitableviewcell unless you have specific max number of possible times.

Comment: Do you have a maximum of items for cells?

Comment: @Larme no, I don't know what max items may be (may be 15, but for every cell that count may change)

Comment: @Vadim Nikolaev, you can add scrollview to your cell, then add the items to the scrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a UIStackView to your UITableViewCell. You can add the labels with the text to the UIStackView.

I wrapped your data into an array.

```
let tableViewData = [["06:58"],
    ["07:13", "07:38", "07:53"],
    ["08:13", "08:38", "08:53"],
    ["09:13", "09:33", "09:53"]]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTime", for: indexPath) as! TimeViewCell

    cell.configure(data: tableViewData[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Then, in for your TimeViewCell, you have to add your UIStackView IBOulet (or add it programmatically) and the configure method.

```
class TimeViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var labelStackView: UIStackView!

    func configure(data: Array<String>) {
        for time in data {
            let timeLabel = UILabel()
            timeLabel.text = time
            labelStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and one question - when i scroll my tableview - my data in every cell add (not refresh) - may be any variant to hide it?

Comment: I'm don't quite understand your question. What do you want to hide?

Comment: when I scroll tableView - I see, that items repeats for every cell

Comment: What do you mean with items? The UILabels?

Comment: yes, when i open VC first time - everything OK, but when I scroll it - labels begin repeats - when I exit from VC and return - everything OK